# React Query - useQuery returns undefined - onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I have following hook which handle all query:

```
const useUsers = (userId: number) => {
    const { data: user } = useQuery([QUERY.USERS, userId],  () =>  getUser(userId))
    
    return {
      user
    }
}

export const getUser = async (userId) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await fetch(`path/path/${userId}`)
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    throw new Error('Something went wrong');
  }
}
```

Now in my main component I invoke this hook:

```
const [userId, setUserId] = useState(null)  
const { user } = useUsers(userId);
```

Also I have a list of user. When I click on user I am setting userId by (setUserId). OnClick Function looks like this:

```
const handleUserDetails = (userId) => {
  setUserId(userId);
  console.log(user) // undefined
}
```

My problem is when I click I got undefined.

Only the second click returns the correct data

Answer (score 0):

The `user` object is `undefined` because when you change the `userId` state, by calling `setUserId(userId)`, a new fetch request is being triggered. Immediately, without waiting, you are calling `console.log(user)`. And because the fetch request hasn't completed yet, the `user` object is still `undefined`.

When you click the button again, if the `userId` is the same as it was on the first click, the `user` object won't be (probably) `undefined` because the fetch request has completed and that's the cached value of the `user` object being displayed.

In order to be able to access the `user` object immediately after the request completes, you can use the `useEffect` hook and put `user` in its dependency list:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // console.log only if user is defined
  if (user) {
    console.log("User won't be undefined here ", user);
  }
}, [user]);
```

[Here's a Codesandbox sample of what I exactly mean](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-panini-dfzh3n?file=/src/App.js)